# Asp.net vNext web app authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I'm trying to rewrite an old mvc1 application as a vNext app in vs2014. Application authenticates against the company's active directory. Here's a bit of a background to help clarify where my confusion is coming from.

I wrote one app in mvc4 which authenticates the following way:
1. Vs template had account login post action with isValid method
2. I wrote my membership provider and registered it through web.config
3. When I run application isValid is now calling my override that does authentication

Now I'm in vNext and here's what I see
1. Same account and login method except there's some signinmanager and user manager passed into it. I'm yet to see where it's coming from exactly. I suspect it's through startup.cs
2. I see that isValid is replaced with something like Passwordsigninasync which I think I need to override to login the user.

Here's my question how do I make Passwordsigninasync authenticate to our AD? I can go solo and ignore the framework to make it work but I'm sure there's an easy way to do it and I'm just missing some understanding of how plumbing works in vNext. Appreciate any help in the right direction.

Comment: 1. vNext is in development so i advice not to use it in production. Only after release. 2. You can search for AD authentication for OWIN. Because OWIN and vNext have similar code structure and middleware approach.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the default implementation of ASP.NET Identity setup, but want it to use Active Directory rather than individual accounts.

See the following for a walkthrough: [On-Premises Organizational Authentication](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/)